# asking a user to reenter data in a 2d array - java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

Good afternoon,

I'm writing a program that asks a user to enter two numbers into a 2d array. The 1st number needs to be between 1 and 20 and the second number needs to be between 1 and 5.

I've written the part to take the input from the user

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class store {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        double[][] maxtrix = new double[4][2];




        for (int i = 0; i < maxtrix.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter the amount of apples (1-20) and oranges (1-5) for bag  " + (i+1) + ": ");

            for (int j = 0; j < maxtrix[i].length; j++) {
                maxtrix[i][j] = input.nextDouble();

            }

        }
```

The question I have is what would be the best way to ask the user to reenter the data if they are outside the given ranges. I have used a do while before to ask a user to reenter if they input is outside the range but can't seem to figure it out within a 2d array.
Thanks for any tips or hints in advance.

Comment: If you are only entering 2 numbers, there is no reason to have two loops set up. You can just fill 
`maxtrix[0][0]`
and
`matrix[0][1]`
Are you trying to fill up every spot in the [4][2] array with inputs?

Comment: Hi yes I am filling ever spot, so user will type 20 5 enter 12 4 enter, 21 5 too many apples please reenter 20 5 enter, 9 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this... I intentionally kept 2 nested loops as you did. You can also enter apples and oranges separately to simplify this.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        double[][] maxtrix = new double[4][2];
        boolean areApplesEntered = false, areOrangesEntered = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < maxtrix.length; i++) {          
            areApplesEntered = false;
            areOrangesEntered = false;
            for (int j = 0; j < maxtrix[i].length; j++) {
                double apples, oranges;
                if (areApplesEntered == false) {
                    do {
                        System.out.println("Enter the # of apples between 1 and 20 for the bag ["+(i+1) +"] -->");
                        apples = input.nextDouble();

                    } while (apples < 1 || apples > 20);

                    maxtrix[i][j] = apples;
                    areApplesEntered = true;
                } else {

                    do {
                        System.out.println("Enter the # of oranges between 1 and 5 for the bag ["+(i+1)+"] -->");
                        oranges = input.nextDouble();

                    } while (oranges < 1 || oranges > 5);

                    maxtrix[i][j] = oranges;
                    areOrangesEntered = true;
                }

            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for all of the help!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to set up some while loops to check for your conditions:

```
System.out.println("Please enter the number of apples (from 1 to 20): ");

while (input.hasNextDouble()) {
    double temp = input.nextDouble();
    if (temp  < 1 || temp  > 20) {
        System.out.println("\nThe number of apples must be a number in [1..20]. \nPlease enter a valid amount: ");
        continue;
    }
    else {
        matrix[0][0] = temp;
        break;
    }
}

System.out.println("Please enter the number of oranges (from 1 to 5): ");

while (input.hasNextDouble()) {
    double temp = input.nextDouble();
    if (temp < 1 || temp > 5) {
        System.out.println("\nThe number of oranges must be a number in [1..5]. \nPlease enter a valid amount: ");
        continue;
    }
    else {
        matrix[0][1] = temp;
        break;
    }

}
```

I am assuming by your post that you are just entering two numbers total..